# JavaCV cvInRangeS Error

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, contour, vision

I'm trying to filter out the contours in an image. My code has no syntax errors but I just get a lot of red text when I run my program. I have located the point of failure to be cvInRangeS.

```
cvInRangeS(imghsv,minc,maxc,imgbin);
```

You can see this with the println statments only making it to "thourgh3"

square.jpg is in the project directory so that shouldn't be the problem if that helps.

The console returnes

```
Through 1
Through 2
Through 3 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1.size == dst.size && dst.type() == CV_8U) in     cvInRangeS, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 2972
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:2972: error: (-215) src1.size == dst.size && dst.type() == CV_8U in function cvInRangeS

at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvInRangeS(Native Method)
at opencv2.OpenCV2.main(OpenCV2.java:50)
Java Result: 1
```

The full code is as follows

```
package opencv2; 


/*There are import statments here but for the sake of space I have left them out :D*/

public class OpenCV2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IplImage img1;
        IplImage imghsv;
        IplImage imgbin;
        CvScalar minc = cvScalar(95,150,75,0), maxc = cvScalar(145,255,255,0);
        CvSeq contour1 = new CvSeq(), contour2;
        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
        double areaMax = 1000, areaC = 0;

        System.out.println("Through 1");

        img1 = cvLoadImage("square.jpg");
        imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),8,3);
        imgbin = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),8,3);
                    System.out.println("Through 2");

        cvCvtColor(img1,imghsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
                    System.out.println("Through 3");

        cvInRangeS(imghsv,minc,maxc,imgbin);
                    System.out.println("Through 4");

        cvFindContours(imgbin,storage,contour1,Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),
                CV_RETR_LIST, CV_LINK_RUNS,cvPoint(0,0));

        contour2 = contour1;

                    System.out.println("Through 5");

        while(contour1 != null && !contour1.isNull()){
        areaC = cvContourArea(contour1,CV_WHOLE_SEQ,1);

        if(areaC > areaMax){
        areaMax  = areaC;
        }

        contour1 = contour1.h_next();
        }//end of while

        while(contour2 != null && !contour2.isNull()){
        areaC = cvContourArea(contour2,CV_WHOLE_SEQ,1);

                    System.out.println("Through 6");

        if(areaC < areaMax){
        cvDrawContours(imgbin,contour2,CV_RGB(0,0,0),CV_RGB(0,0,0),
                0,CV_FILLED,8,cvPoint(0,0));
            }//end of if

                    System.out.println("Through 7");
        contour2 = contour2.h_next();
        }//end of while2

                    System.out.println("Through 8");
        cvShowImage("Color",img1);
        cvShowImage("CF",img1);
        cvWaitKey();

        cvReleaseImage(img1);
        cvReleaseImage(imghsv);
        cvReleaseImage(imgbin);
        cvReleaseMemStorage(storage);

    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 1):

`cvInRangeS()` assumes the type of the input image to be `CV_8U`, so you have to convert it first.

```
...
cvtColor(imghsv, grayscale, CV_BGR2GRAY ); 
cvInRangeS(grayscale,minc,maxc,imgbin);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. the problem was in this line I have it set to a 3 channel image "3"'
       imgbin = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),8,3);

It should be a binary image.
    imgbin = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),8,1);

Comment: Thanks for your help. your comment led me to the discovery!